# MongoDB return nested array of objects minus a property within the object (also .then() doesn't work with aggregation)

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, nested, slice

I'm very new to mongodb and am having difficulty getting to a solution for my use case. For example I have the following document:

```
{ 
   _id : ObjectId('5rtgwr6gsrtbsr6hsfbsr6bdrfyb'),
   uuid : 'something',
   mainArray : [
       {
           id : 1,
           title: 'A',
           array: ['lots','off','stuff']
       },
       {
           id : 2,
           title: 'B',
           array: ['even','more','stuff']
       }
   ]
}
```

I'd like to have the following returned:

```
{ 
   uuid : 'something',
   mainArray : [
       {
           id : 1,
           title: 'A'
       },
       {
           id : 2,
           title: 'B'
       }
   ]
}
```

I've tried various combinations of using `findOne()` and `aggregate()` with `$slice` and `$project`. With `findOne()`, if it worked at all, the who document would be returned. I am unable to test whether attempts at aggregating work because `.then((ret)=>{})` promises don't seem to work in node.js for me with it (no issues with `findOne`). Calling a function like so

```
return db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
       $match: {
          _id:ObjectId(mongo_id)
       }  
    },
    {
        $project : {
            mainArray: {
                id:1,
                title:1
            }
        }
    }
],function(err,res){
    console.log(res)
    return res
})
```

logs the entire function and not the droids I'm looking for.

Comment: For logging only the result set,I think you're returning the cursor object instead of the result set, try `return db.myCollection.aggregate([matchCode,projectCode]).toArray().then(data => { console.log(res); return res; }, error => {console.log(error)})`

Comment: Also what are your matchCode and projectCode objects used in aggregate function?

Comment: Thanks, issue resolves! My instinct on how to construct the project code was valid, missing piece of the puzzle was `toArray()`. I could pm you the matchCode and projectCode so you can at least put it down as the answer for me to up-vote. I'm glad I know now but how does one come across such knowledge? I saw no reference to it on any of the sites and pages I looked at while researching this.

Comment: Glad to help, I will add an answer with reference to mongodb docs. No need of your query object as it was not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing toArray() method to obtain the actual result set. Instead you're returning the aggregation cursor object. Try this.

```
return db.myCollection.aggregate([matchCode,projectCode]).toArray().then(
     data => { 
              console.log(data); 
              return data; 
             }, 
     error => { console.log(error)});
```

> The documnetation on aggregation cursor for MongoDB NodeJS driver can
>   be found here
>   http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/AggregationCursor.html#toArray

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution (to the solution mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374994/mongodb-return-nested-array-of-objects-minus-a-property-within-the-object-also#comment110315796_62374994) by @v1shva)

Instead of using aggregation you can use `projection` option of `.findOne()` operation.

```
db.myCollection.findOne(matchCode, { 
  projection: { _id: false, 'mainArray.array': false } // or { _id: -1, 'mainArray.array': -1 }
})
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Would you be able to say there were any advantages to using this approach over aggregation? EDIT: Perhaps the fact that I can specify which one or two properties to opt out, rather than specify which ones to opt IN?

Comment: You can actually use the same code in projection option in `$project` stage of your aggregation to just opting out `{ $project: { _id: false, 'mainArray.array': false } }`. With `.findOne()` you get one document. With `.find()` or `.aggregate()` you get multiple documents. There is no other difference than that for your case.

Comment: Could you tell me what the code would be for returning the `array` within the first item of `mainArray`, or rather the item that satisfies a condition such as most recent date, with every other item ignoring `array`? I feel cheeky asking without putting any effort in to get to the solution myself, but it seems like another thing I could spend countless hours on needlessly when what we're all looking for is efficiency ;) Thank you kindly in advance!

Comment: @MikeyB Where should we check for the condition? con the `array` itself or on the `mainArray` or the document? It heavily depends on the condition, could be very simple or a bit complex. I would suggest you posting a new question with more specific details, that would be in a better format than a comment. Also depending on your requirement `$project` with `$$REMOVE` variable might help you.

Comment: mainArray, but I shall notify here with a link to the new question once I've created it

Comment: I've put something up here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62386313/mongodb-assymetrical-return-of-data-first-item-in-array-returned-in-full-the-r