# MongoDB assymetrical return of data, first item in array returned in full, the rest with certain properties omitted?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements, projection

I'm new to MongoDB and getting to grips with its syntax and capabilities. To achieve the functionality described in the title I believe I can create a promise that will run 2 simultaneous queries on the document - one to get the full content of one item in the array (or at least the data that is omitted in the other query, to re-add after), searched for by most recent date, the other to return the array minus specific properties. I have the following document:

```js
{ 
  _id : ObjectId('5rtgwr6gsrtbsr6hsfbsr6bdrfyb'),
  uuid : 'something',
  mainArray : [
      {
          id : 1,
          title: 'A',
          date: 05/06/2020,
          array: ['lots','off','stuff']
      },
      {
          id : 2,
          title: 'B',
          date: 28/05/2020,
          array: ['even','more','stuff']
      },
      {
          id : 3,
          title: 'C',
          date: 27/05/2020,
          array: ['mountains','of','knowledge']
      }
  ]
}
```

and I would like to return

```js
{ 
  uuid : 'something',
  mainArray : [
      {
          id : 1,
          title: 'A',
          date: 05/06/2020,
          array: ['lots','off','stuff']
      },
      {
          id : 2,
          title: 'B'
      },
      {
          id : 3,
          title: 'C'
      }
  ]
}
```

How valid and performant is the promise approach versus constructing one query that would achieve this? I have no idea how to perform such 'combined-rule'/conditions in MongoDB, if anyone could give an example?

Comment: You can do an aggregation query and use the [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) array operator to shape the documents as you want. `$map` allows iterate all the elements in the array field  and apply some action on each element.

Comment: If you planned to combine them in node.js. You could equally do only the full query and do field omission processing  in node.js

Comment: I considered that but it feels inefficient, moving around larger amounts of data than is necessary, even just between the database and server - is it? In that case the promise approach would be enough

Comment: Or, is it a valid alternative to have a separate array that stores the basic list data from `mainArray`, alongside a key-value object that stores the nested `array`?

Comment: @MikeyB whether it's a valid alternative or not largely depends on your data access pattern.

Comment: Data access pattern is new terminology for me. This is where my questions lie now, as in which approach to take. Is there a forum you operate in or some way I could spell out my use-case so that you can advise based on your experience? Stack doesn't seem to like conceptual questions, and users get rabid when you don't show code to show that you've tried ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your subdocument array you want to omit is not very large. I would just remove it at the application side. Doing processing in MongoDB means you choose to use the compute resources of MongoDB instead of your application. Generally your application is easier and cheaper to scale, so implementation at the application layer is preferable.

But in this exact case it's not too complex to implement it in MongoDB:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { // keep the first element somewhere
      first: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$mainArray", 0] }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { // remove the subdocument field
      "mainArray.array": false
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: { // join the first element with the rest of the transformed array
      mainArray: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [ // first element
            "$first"
          ],
          { // select elements from the transformed array except the first
            $slice: ["$mainArray", 1, { $size: "$mainArray" }]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { // remove the temporary first elemnt
      "first": false
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zq5JsH1YEbE)